# laravel try/catch doesn't work for a failed query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

i have a INSERT query which might fail due to certain unique key in database so im using try/catch to avoid the error ...btw `form_id` is unique

```
    try {

        $reward = new UserCreditForm();
        $reward->user_id = $form->user_id ;
        $reward->form_id = $form->id ;
        $reward->amount = $amount ;
        $reward->result = $result ;
        $reward->save();
        $form->result = $result ;
        $form->save();

    }
    catch ( Exception $e )
    {
        $form->error_flag = 6 ;
        $form->save();
    }
```

but try/catch doesnt workwhen uniqu key fails and i get

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
(2/2) QueryException

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user_credit_forms_form_id_unique' (SQL: insert into `user_credit_forms` (`user_id`, `form_id`, `amount`, `result`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2, 1, 499392, 1, 2017-08-31 14:45:06, 2017-08-31 14:45:06))
```

is there anyway to avoide the error and jump on the catche part if query fails ?

Comment: Try `catch ( \Exception $e )`

Comment: @Yupik thanx pleas post it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `catch ( \Exception $e )` to catch all exceptions in `try`.

Final form should look like this:

```
try {

    $reward = new UserCreditForm();
    $reward->user_id = $form->user_id ;
    $reward->form_id = $form->id ;
    $reward->amount = $amount ;
    $reward->result = $result ;
    $reward->save();
    $form->result = $result ;
    $form->save();

}
catch ( \Exception $e )
{
    $form->error_flag = 6 ;
    $form->save();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Way 1:**

You need to use

```
\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e
```

in your `catch`

```
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
```

---

Reference for [`QueryException`](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.html)

---

**Way 2:**

You can alternatively use:

```
} catch (\Exception $e) {
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `Exception $e` it tells PHP to look for the class `Exception` in the current namespace. Since your code is most likely inside a Laravel controller then the current namespace is most likely to be `App\Http\Controllers`. Since class `App\Http\Controllers\Exception` does not exist you catch nothing. You need to write `\Exception $e` to tell PHP to look for the `Exception` class in the global namespace.